# Python3.8 Asyncio run_forever() stuck in loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I have a program in Python3.8 but I can't find the error. Maybe you can help me...
As soon as I start the main.py (program code is below) it loops for ages (have had it running for over 24 hours already). If I interrupt it, the error message below comes from Asyncio. Anyone an idea to fix it?

**Error Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david\IdeaProjects\studienarbeit\backend\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 434, in select
    self._poll(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 783, in _poll
    status = _overlapped.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(self._iocp, ms)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

**Programmcode of main.py:**

```
import asyncio

import api
from frameserver import FrameServer
from motiondetection.bsmotiondetector import BSMotionDetector
from motiondetection.motiondetectionresult import MotionDetectionResult
from recorder import Recorder, RecordingTrigger
from tinydbconnector import TinyDBConnector
from websocketserver import WebsocketServer

db = TinyDBConnector('data/db.json')
frameserver = FrameServer(db)
websocketserver = WebsocketServer(frameserver)
recorder = Recorder(frameserver, db)


async def run():
    cameras = db.get_cameras()
    if cameras is not None:
        for cam in cameras:
            asyncio.create_task(frameserver.capture(cam))
        motiondetector = BSMotionDetector(db, frameserver)
        motiondetector.run().subscribe(on_next=lambda res: asyncio.create_task(motion_result_handler(res)))
    asyncio.create_task(websocketserver.run())
    asyncio.create_task(api.run(frameserver, db))


async def motion_result_handler(result: MotionDetectionResult):
    msg = "result from " + result.camera.name + ": " + str(result.motion) + " (Magnitude: " + str(
        result.intensity) + ")"
    print(msg)
    await websocketserver.broadcast_event("MotionResult", result)
    if result.motion:
        await recorder.capture_while_motion(result.camera, RecordingTrigger.MOTION, 10)
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(run())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I know that the programm worked before. But it isn´t anymore and i cant find how to fix it.

Comment: Why would you think a function called `run_forever` would stop? Also, keyboard interrupt error will trigger no matter the code when you interrupt it. Please provide what you actually want so we can help your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It should start a backend database but the frontend cant connect to it. I thought the run_forever isnt working right.